# If GCC build option with '-mms-bitfields' , the 'epoll_event.data.u64' value can be truncated to 4-byte value via 'epoll_wait'

Tags: c++, gcc, centos6, epoll

If GCC build option with `-mms-bitfields` , the `epoll_event.data.u64` value can be truncated to 4-byte value via `epoll_wait`.

I've a example for socket server using `epoll` and I find it very strange, when I buid with `-mms-bitfields`, I can't get the orignal 8-byte value in `epoll_event.data.u64`. I don't known why, and can I fix it in some way?

The is code following:

```
...
    {
        epoll_event ev;
        ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLET;

        ev.data.u64 = 0x123456789abcdef0;

        printf("epoll_ctl add:size=%ld, ptr=%p, u64=%lu\n", sizeof(ev.data.ptr), ev.data.ptr, ev.data.u64);

        nRetCode = epoll_ctl(nEpollHandle, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, nSocket, &ev);
        printf("epoll_ctl retcode=%d\n", nRetCode);
        SOCKET_JMP_ERROR(nRetCode >= 0);
    }

    // test wait
    {
        int nRetCount = 0;
        int nRemainEventCount = 1;
        epoll_event EpollEvent;
        epoll_event * pEpollEvent = &EpollEvent;

        nRetCount = epoll_wait(nEpollHandle, pEpollEvent, nRemainEventCount, 0);
        printf("epoll_wait nRetCount=%d\n", nRetCount);
        SOCKET_JMP_ERROR(nRetCount >= 0);

        printf("epoll_wait wait:size=%ld, ptr=%p, u64=%lu\n", sizeof((pEpollEvent->data).ptr), (pEpollEvent->data).ptr, (pEpollEvent->data).u64);

    }
...
```

And build without `-mms-bitfields`, output message is this:

```
epoll_ctl add:size=8, ptr=0x123456789abcdef0, u64=1311768467463790320
epoll_ctl retcode=0
epoll_wait nRetCount=1
epoll_wait wait:size=8, ptr=0x123456789abcdef0, u64=1311768467463790320
```

If build option with `-mms-bitfields`, the message is:

```
epoll_ctl add:size=8, ptr=0x123456789abcdef0, u64=1311768467463790320
epoll_ctl retcode=0
epoll_wait nRetCount=1
epoll_wait wait:size=8, ptr=0x9abcdef0, u64=2596069104
```

This the GCC version by `gcc -v`:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux
Configured with: ../configure -build=x86_64-linux -enable-checking=release -enable-languages=c,c++ -disable-multilib --with-gmp --with-mpfr --with-mpc
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 (GCC)
```

Then the OS is `CentOS 6.5`:

```
Linux version 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013
```

Can someone explain this problem, please? Thank you....

Comment: The `-mms-bitfields` option changes the ABI, so I would expect it to break all kinds of things. Can you explain why you are you using it, what you are trying to achieve? There may be a better way. You shouldn't use that option unless you understand what it does and what the implications are.

Comment: Because I want to use struct bitfields, and the client is build by msvc, so the protocol of communication for the client-to-server maybe need '-mms-bitfields'. For example:    struct SayHelloToClient
    {
        int a: 1;
        int b: 1;
        int c: 2;
    }

Comment: I believe you can use the `ms_struct` attribute on individual structure types rather than compiling with `-mms-bitfields`. That should solve that problem. I'll put more detail in an answer below.

Comment: @ccccycccc You are writing code running on linux, you can not use `-mms-bitfields` when you are building that code, it WILL mess up many things. At best you can put an attribute on individual structs that you want to share between your linux and msvc code, but there is no guarantee that the MSVC and gcc compiler are going to be ABI compatible for the memory layout a whole struct - so you are somewhat on your own in doing that, and have to do your own experiments if you want to go down that path.

Comment: Well,I’ll have a try,thanks.Maybe I can solve it in my example,but in actually this problem occurs in another project.So I should discuss with my teammates. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you all friends!Maybe it could run well in 32-bit before...

Answer (score 1):

The `-mms-bitfields` changes the way structures are laid out and in some cases could cause structures defined in system headers to be incompatible with your system library ABI. That is most likely the reason why `epoll` behaves incorrectly when `-mms-bitfields` is used.

If compiling 32-bit code, you can apply MS structure layout to individual structures by using `__attribute__((ms_struct))`, which might be the best way forward, eg:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct a
{
  short a :16;
  int   : 0;
  short b :16;
} __attribute__((ms_struct)) aa;

int main()
{
  printf("sizeof struct a = %d\n", (int)sizeof(struct a));
  printf("sizeof aa = %d\n", (int)sizeof(aa));
  return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
sizeof struct a = 8
sizeof aa = 8
```

Without the `__attribute__((ms_struct))` (and without `-mms-bitfields`) it instead reports a size of 6.

Comment: Thank you friend,I’ll try to use attribute instead.